# How to Show a Term in TinyIdris?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I am trying to follow the code of [TinyIdris](https://github.com/edwinb/SPLV20/blob/master/TinyIdris-v2/src/Core/TT.idr) and print out the basic definitions such as `Term`s. But I couldn't apply the `Show` instance defined for `Term` due to a syntax I am not familiar with. (I am a beginner for Idris2 and dependent types).

The `Term` data type and its depdent `Name` type is defined in the above link as follows:

```
public export
data Name : Type where
     UN : String -> Name -- user written name
     MN : String -> Int -> Name -- machine generated name

-- ...

public export
data Term : List Name -> Type where
     Local : (idx : Nat) -> -- de Bruijn index
             (0 p : IsVar name idx vars) -> -- proof that index is valid
             Term vars
     Ref : NameType -> Name -> Term vars -- a reference to a global name
     Meta : Name -> List (Term vars) -> Term vars
     Bind : (x : Name) -> -- any binder, e.g. lambda or pi
            Binder (Term vars) ->
            (scope : Term (x :: vars)) -> -- one more name in scope
            Term vars
     App : Term vars -> Term vars -> Term vars -- function application
     TType : Term vars
     Erased : Term vars

-- ...
```

I am trying to find a minimal working example. I guess the `Ref` constructor is the easiest (and non trivial) to construct. And I constructed a `Term` value:

```
Ref (TyCon 0 0) (UN "Nat")
```

, which type-checks in the REPL when the `Core.TT` module is loaded.

```
:t Ref (TyCon 0 0) (UN "Nat")
Ref (TyCon 0 0) (UN "Nat") : Term ?vars
```

I am trying to use this to express the type `Nat`. (Not sure if this is actually a correct expression). But then, I have trouble using the `Show` instance declaration near the end of the file (listed below) to print it:

```
export 
{vars : _} -> Show (Term vars) where
  show tm = let (fn, args) = getFnArgs tm in showApp fn args
    where
      showApp : {vars : _} -> Term vars -> List (Term vars) -> String
      showApp (Local {name} idx p) []
         = show (nameAt idx p) ++ "[" ++ show idx ++ "]"
      showApp (Ref _ n) [] = show n
      -- ...
```

When I print it in the REPL as follows:

```
show $ Ref (TyCon 0 0) (UN "Nat")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't find an implementation for Show (Term ?vars).

(Interactive):1:1--1:34
 1 | show $ Ref (TyCon 0 0) (UN "Nat")
```

So it seems that the way I called `show` does not match the `Show` instance declaration, which I didn't understand to begin with. Unlike the other `Show` instances I saw in the file, it has a prefix that looks like an implicit argument.

```
{vars : _} -> Show (Term vars) where
```

I am not sure how to interpret this. I've seen prerequisites such as `Show a => Show MyList a`. But I don't understand the prefix `{vars : _} ->`  here, and how to call `show` properly to satisfy this prefix part.

*Could someone help explain how to interpret this syntax of instance declaration and how to use it to show the Term (or another example Term)?*